# Using Ableton hardware (Push/Launchpad) as a custom controller

Tags: windows

I would like to use the Ableton Push as a controller for my robot. The robot is controlled through a Windows program using an Xbox Controller at the moment.
However, there just isn't enough buttons on the Xbox controller for everything we want to do, so originally my thought (since it supports multiple Xbox controllers) was to plug in an external USB keyboard to my laptop and get a program that maps it as if it was an Xbox controller. Then I thought, why use a keyboard, why not use a Launchpad and write a program myself to map the Launchpad to this program (I have the ability to modify the program to pick up more buttons than just the Xbox mappings).
So, my question is this, is it possible to do this? I think I could do it from the programming perspective (just by writing a program that interprets the input from the controller itself, and sends commands to control lighting etc. on the Launchpad/Push), and just wanted to make sure before I buy one in case there is some reason, for example hardware inside of the devices that handles controls rather than sending the raw input to the computer as it looks like the screens on the Push are controlled internally, not externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it seems this question basically got ignored, I'll answer with what I've found out so far: I am yet to find anything out regarding the Ableton Push, but with the Novation Launchpad S, I have discovered that Novation have released all of the documentation I need to be able to hack their hardware here http://us.novationmusic.com/support/product-downloads?product=Launchpad. So I've ordered myself a Launchpad now.